# What do women do when they're "ministering" in front of God's tabernacle?

Tags: exodus, gender, tabernacle

[Exodus 38:8](http://biblehub.com/exodus/38-8.htm) says that the bronze basin of the Tabernacle and its bronze stand was made from the mirrors of the women who served at the entrance to the tent of meeting.

Why do those women need mirrors? So they look pretty? Are they entertainers?

Comment: Hi Jim, I see the NIV translators understood this passage to mean that these mirrors were donated by the women who served.  This would not necessarily mean they needed  mirrors in their service.  Generally speaking, it seems natural to me that women would have mirrors; and that, upon realizing their mirrors were made of the material needed to make the basin, they would willingly donate the mirrors for the cause.

Comment: What would be a proper tag? I was suspicious that the women are actually prostitutes and mirrors are necessary to make them pretty so people come. Of course, that's an outrageous idea. I just want to know the truth. I think someone actually make that as answer and no body else dispute that

Comment: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7527/who-are-the-prostitutes-in-deuteronomy-2318/7544?noredirect=1#comment14825_7544 an answer there says that the women are prostitutes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate translation is “assembling” rather than “ministering”; the relevant root is צבא, see, *e.g.*, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%90). Try this translation on for size:

> He made the washstand of copper and its base of copper; from the mirrors of the assembled [women], who congregated at the entrance of the tent of meeting.

The translation of “ministering” is somewhat suspect anyhow; no rôle for women in the Tabernacle is ever mentioned.

---

But why does the text make such a point of the fact that the women assembled? Here the Midrash expands on the story, as quoted by [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9899#v=8&showrashi=true):

> The Israelite women tried to donate their mirrors, which they had used to beautify themselves with, as a contribution for the Tabernacle. Moses at first rejected these mirrors, since they were tools for lust. But God told Moses, accept them: during the years of servitude in Egypt these women went to lengths to make themselves attractive to their husbands; and only because of this are there the **legions** [another, more literal meaning of the root צבא] of Israelites today.

(My free translation.)

Answer (score 2):

The text does not say what the women did when they were ministering.  Possibly they were greeting people as they entered the temple? Possibly helped direct visitors or provided a cup of water to thirsty visitors? Maybe they just kept things clean and organized?

Regarding the mirrors, it seems that the women were not very vain for otherwise they would not be willing to give them up for making of the bronze basin. Those women who were ministers upon hearing the needs of the bronze material for the basin brought from their homes their own bronze mirrors and gave them sacrificially.   I do not think we are to associate their mirrors kept at home with their service at the temple, for there is no purpose anywhere recorded in the use of mirrors in the religious ceremonies in the temple.

Some commentators mention that Egyptians often took mirrors into temples but I am not sure what for exactly. From this they think possibly Moses was forbidding the practice by forcing the women to give up their mirrors. However, it seems more natural just to assume that the women volunteered to give up their personal possessions due to the high quality of the bronze used in mirror making. These materials would be suitable for the crafting of the basin and may have appeared to have the same shiny and reflective appearance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an article on the topic:
https://www.academia.edu/4303429/The_Ministering_Women_and_their_Mirrors
There are no Hebrew words for prostitute in Exodus 38:8 so they are probably not prostitutes. These women are also mentioned in 1 Sam 2:22. I think the Hebrew word tsaba is key to working out what the women were doing as the article explains.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the temple within the pictographs speaks of the Bride and bride-hood, the basen was a symbolic of being washed and clean, pure before they entered speaking of the virgin daughters of Zion but only the Aaonite priest entered the actual Wedding chamber. Showing not only the Bride but her children too shall be brought to the king.

Comment: Welcome to the Hermeneutics forum, John. This forum is different from most others because it's expected that you research and support your posted answer with evidence from scriptural, linguistic, manuscript, commentaries from early writers, or scholarly sources. We're not supposed to offer just our opinion, in this case focused on possible symbolism. You might want to review some highly rated answers to get a better idea of what's expected. Hope this helps and best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult for me to accept the many accusations against women when something like this comes up. It’s ridiculous to assume that women somehow are so awful because they own a mirror and therefore must be prostitutes. Let’s just go back to the fact that if the men were so holy and better than women, there wouldn’t be any need for a women to practice prostitution!! In my experience there have been few women that are as sex crazed as men. So forget the garbage that one sex is better than the other. Man ( women and men) need to consecrate their lives fully to God. Men aren’t corrupted because of women nor are women corrupted because of men. Get your lives right with God!! God is not more honored by a sanctified male over female!! Anna ministered in the temple unto the Lord! It’s just not true that God ever held males in higher regard spiritually than women or the other way around!! Women are care takers of their children so naturally will not be able to minister as freely in actual physical duties. They are not less holy because of this. It is ministry unto the Lord to raise children. It is Holiness unto the Lord to raise godly children. Moses mother was the one recorded to have had faith to place her child in the river Nile.
I am so fed up with this biased attitude towards females in the body of Christ!! In the New Testament Paul tells the church to support Women laboring in the gospel. Not all women are their entire lives raising children and are qualified to preach the gospel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).